# Bootstrap 5 navbar with dropdown menus will not work

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

This navbar contains dropdown menus that don't work while converting from Bootstrap v5.2.2 to v5.2.3. It does not dropdown, instead staying still. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="page">
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">AT Products LLC</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsibleNavbar" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/">AT Products</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Products</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/paid">Paid Services</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/flash">Flash Documentation</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/sms">SMS Bomb</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/mdickie">MDickie Projects</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/bxpp">BxPP</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version. Note that tags do not belong in titles.

Comment: Down vote as I would expect someone to check the console for error messages before posting a question.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't change the bundled javascript:

```
<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```html
   <html lang="en">
<head>    
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">  
        <script src="/static/purecookie.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
      <div id="page">
    <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">AT Products LLC</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsibleNavbar" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/">AT Products</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Products</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/paid">Paid Services</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/flash">Flash Documentation</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/sms">SMS Bomb</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/mdickie">MDickie Projects</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/bxpp">BxPP</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
        </header>  
      </div>
      <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Still doesn't make the dropdowns any different. Doesn't work.

Comment: have you replaced the stubborn javascript cdn

Comment: @AlexToucan, it clearly _does_ work. Did you look at the demo in this answer?

Comment: @rustam, your answer would be better with more explanation. I didn't understand it until I had written my own answer. See [answer] and take the [tour] for tips.

Comment: up voted, but only after @isherwood provided the full explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I get the impression that you simply updated the version in your CDN code. That won't work. The integrity key must match the actual file. You can see the error in the browser console:

> Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource

Make sure you copy the new code from the [CDN](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="page">
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">AT Products LLC</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsibleNavbar" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/">AT Products</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Products</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/paid">Paid Services</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/flash">Flash Documentation</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/sms">SMS Bomb</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/mdickie">MDickie Projects</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/bxpp">BxPP</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```